# Should I use "unsigned" every time i know I'm processing unsigned values?

Tags: c++, signedness

Often values are known to be positive. For example TCP/UDP sequence number is always positive value. Both `int` and `unsigned int` are big enough to store even the biggest `sequence number` so I can use any of these types. There are many other examples when values are known to be positive.

Are there any reasons to use `unsigned` type when capacity of regular `signed` type is enough (and often more than enough)?

Personally I tend to use regular types because:

- `int` is probably a little bit more readable than `uint` or `unsigned int`
- I don't need to include extra headers for `UINT` etc.
- I will avoid extra casts somewhere further in the program

Reasons to use `unsigned` type I can imagine:

- help compiler generated better code?
- help another programmer to understand that variable is unsigned
- avoid possible bugs (for example when int is assigned to UINT compiler likely will generate compile-time error and we should check that value we assign is not negative)

Comment: Some thoughts about it here: http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/08/a-tutorial-on-signed-and-unsigned-integers/

Comment: thanks, also I've found that question just now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225521/should-unsigned-ints-be-used-if-not-necessary?rq=1

Comment: No.  There are some arguments against using `unsigned` - Stroustrup alludes to this in passing in The C++ Programming Language somewhere - Lakos went off and wrote a chapter about it in one of his books: tedious.  Example issues: if you have values a and b, `abs(a - b)` tends to work intuitively for ints but not unsigned; and it's noteworthy that Standard conversions can kick in silently so the kind of checks you might hope to get from using unsigned don't work anyway - negative values become silently huge and vice versa.

Comment: Mixing signed and unsigned is an important source of bugs. I would stick to signed in all but specialist situations.

Comment: Me too; unsigned types are really nice, but they come with many gotchas, plus messier syntax.

Comment: @john: not mixing them means not using STL at all?

Comment: Andrew Koenig wrote a nice article about this: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/unsigned-arithmetic-useful-but-tricky/240001198

Comment: @AndyT It's unfortunate that the STL uses unsigned types.

Comment: @john: yeah, I mean if you use STL you cannot avoid using unsigned ints, and since you're already mixing ints I think it's less error-prone to use unsigned ints when apropriate.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that comparing signed and unsigned numbers can lead to surprising results. In C and (I think) C++, comparing signed and unsigned numbers causes the signed number to be interpreted as unsigned. If the signed value happens to be negative, reading it as unsigned will give a LARGER value than any unsigned number, which is not what you want. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16161107/643383) for an example in Objective-C, which uses the same conversion rules as C.